# JS .load() not working inside a triple parameter url rewrite?

Tags: javascript, php

im building a backoffice which has already this function working on single parameter url like **example.com/backoffice/page** 
but on this page is not working the link is like this : **example.com/backoffice/editassembly/2**

### **This is the JS code of the page :**

```
// When the document is ready set up our sortable with it's inherant function(s)
$("#todos").sortable({
    handle: "#handle",
    update: function() {
        var order = $('#todos').sortable('serialize');
        $("#info").load("../scripts/ficheiroassembleia.php?" + order);
    }
});
```

This code is completly correct and working on other pages, the thing is that the `.load` is not loading my script like it could not reach it.

The current module for the page im using is inside the folder **"www/backoffice/modules/editassembly/"** and the script is inside **"www/scripts/"**

Comment: Any errors in console? Do you actually get correct response?

Comment: You need to either modify the _relative_ path you are using there accordingly each time, matching the “depth” of the current document path - or use absolute paths to begin with (starting with a leading `/`.)

Answer (score 0):

I already found out the problem, it was due to fact that the include for header that contained all important js files was not loading corretly, path issue i had to make a call on the file itself since it was the only module using a tripple parameter.